# Python 3 code to read CSV file, manipulate then create new file....works, but looking for improvements

Tags: csv, numpy, python-3.x

This is my first ever post here. I am trying to learn a bit of Python. Using Python 3 and numpy.

Did a few tutorials then decided to dive in and try a little project I might find useful at work as thats a good way to learn for me.

I have written a program that reads in data from a CSV file which has a few rows of headers, I then want to extract certain columns from that file based on the header names, then output that back to a new csv file in a particular format.

The program I have works fine and does what I want, but as I'm a newbie I would like some tips as to how I can improve my code.

My main data file (csv) is about 57 columns long and about 36 rows deep so not big.

It works fine, but looking for advice & improvements.

```
import csv
import numpy as np

#make some arrays..at least I think thats what this does
A=[]
B=[]
keep_headers=[]

#open the main data csv file 'map.csv'...need to check what 'r' means
input_file = open('map.csv','r')

#read the contents of the file into 'data'
data=csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=',')

#skip the first 2 header rows as they are junk
next(data)
next(data)

#read in the next line as the 'header'
headers = next(data)

#Now read in the numeric data (float) from the main csv file 'map.csv'
A=np.genfromtxt('map.csv',delimiter=',',dtype='float',skiprows=5)

#Get the length of a column in A
Alen=len(A[:,0])

#now read the column header values I want to keep from 'keepheader.csv'
keep_headers=np.genfromtxt('keepheader.csv',delimiter=',',dtype='unicode_')

#Get the length of keep headers....i.e. how many headers I'm keeping. 
head_len=len(keep_headers)

#Now loop round extracting all the columns with the keep header titles and
#append them to array B
i=0
while i < head_len:
    #use index to find the apprpriate column number. 
    item_num=headers.index(keep_headers[i])
    i=i+1

    #append the selected column to array B
    B=np.append(B,A[:,item_num])

#now reshape the B array 
B=np.reshape(B,(head_len,36))

#now transpose it as thats the format I want. 
B=np.transpose(B)

#save the array B back to a new csv file called 'cmap.csv'
np.savetxt('cmap.csv',B,fmt='%.3f',delimiter=",")
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can greatly simplify your code using more of `numpy` capabilities.

```
A = np.loadtxt('stack.txt',skiprows=2,delimiter=',',dtype=str)
keep_headers=np.loadtxt('keepheader.csv',delimiter=',',dtype=str)

headers = A[0,:]
cols_to_keep = np.in1d( headers, keep_headers )

B = np.float_(A[1:,cols_to_keep])
np.savetxt('cmap.csv',B,fmt='%.3f',delimiter=",")
```

Comment: Thanks, I may never have found the 'in1d' part, that's very handy. I can see my initial code, although working, could really be improved. Great.

Comment: @user2551578 Thank you. you can accept this answer if you think it fits your needs...